# How can I loop through all categories to display each category post separately?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a simple wordpress site. I've created a home page named home.php and trying to dynamically display posts separately according to category. the code is the following:

```
<?php 
    get_header();  
?>

<main id="main" class="row">
    <?php
        $categories = ['politics' => 'রাজনীতি', 'finance' => 'অর্থনীতি', 'sports' => 'ক্রীড়া', 'entertainment' => 'বিনোদন', 'fenii' => 'আমাদের ফেনী', 'religion' => 'ধর্ম', 'literature' => 'সাহিত্য', 'study' => 'পড়া-লেখা', 'quiz' => 'কুইজ', 'zodiac' => 'রাশিফল'];
        foreach($categories as $key => $category):
            $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                'category_name' => $category,
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    ?>
        <section id="<?php echo $key ?>" class="col-sm-6 section">
        <h3 class="title"> <?php echo $query->query['category_name'] ; ?> </h3>   
       <?php    
            if ( $query->have_posts()):
                while ( $query->have_posts() ):
                    $query->the_post();
        ?> 
                <h5><a href=" <?php the_permalink() ?> "> <?php the_title() ?> </a> </h5>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p> </a>
    <?php       
            endwhile;
                echo "<hr />";
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else:
                echo "<h6> Sorry! No post has been found of this type. </h6>";
                echo "<hr />";
            endif;
    ?>
        <hr />
        </section>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
</main>

<?php 
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

But, no post is displayed like the following:

[image: output]

So, how can I display my posts according to category dynamically by foreach loop as I've been trying since the beginning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `category_id` as the argument for category instead of `category_name` in your `$query_args`?

Also, you should get your categories dynamically instead of creating the array for categories manually. Otherwise, you'll have a problem if you add or remove categories in the future. Have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jenny Ryden, for your helpful information.

Comment: @NewBegin No problem! I'm happy it helped.